# Dressed up vs Handsome

Tags: adjectives

What are the differences between *Dressed up* and *Handsome*? As in:

> You're all dressed up!

Does *dressed up* mean like *handsome*?

Answer (score 2):

The idiom [to dress up](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dress+up) means to wear fancy or formal clothing.  For example:

> Can I wear jeans and a t-shirt to the restaurant, or do I have to dress up?

The word [handsome](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/handsome?s=t) describes a person who is physically attractive, usually with the connotation of having pleasing proportions or being well put-together.  It's more often applied to men than to women, at least in modern use.

So while being **dressed up** is not quite the same as being **handsome**, it is often true that being **dressed up** might make someone **more handsome**.  It's not necessary though - someone who looks uncomfortable or awkward in fancy clothes might be **all dressed up** but not any more handsome than they would be in more comfortable casual clothing.